# Как клонировать блок но с другим ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

```
<html>

<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
function cloNeN() {
$("#ih, #ih1, #ih2").clone()                // сделаем копию элемента Привет, Пока, Привет
.addClass("newElement")         // добавим этой копии класс newElement
.appendTo("#clone");        // вставим измененный элемент в конец элемента clone
}
</script>

</head>

<body onload="cloNeN()">

<div id="container">
<div id="ih" class="hello">Привет</div>
<div id="ih1" class="goodbye">Пока</div>
<div id="ih2" class="hello">Привет</div>
</div>

</br>

<div id="clone"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать так, как на [офф. сайте.](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) Используя `.clone().appendTo().attr();`

---

`.attr() ->` [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
Сперва указываем сам атрибут, а потом его значение. Пример: `.attr('src', 'img/1.png');`

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    function cloneN() {
      var id = ['ih', 'ih1', 'ih2'];
      id.forEach(function(item, i, id) {
        $('#' + item).clone().attr('class', 'newElement' + item).appendTo('#clone');
      });
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="cloneN()">

  <div id="container">
    <div id="ih" class="hello">Привет</div>
    <div id="ih1" class="goodbye">Пока</div>
    <div id="ih2" class="hello">Привет</div>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div id="clone">
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: А чем ваш ответ отличается от вопроса? Я сегодня не выспался, что то не могу найти.. А, нашел - вы избавили ТС от добавления класса 'newElement' и от комментариев. А где  другой id?

Comment: @Darth, исправил.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function cloNeN() {
  // для элементов Привет, Пока, Привет
  [...document.querySelectorAll('#ih, #ih1, #ih2')].forEach(element => {
     // сделаем копию
     const newNode = element.cloneNode();
     // не забудем скопировать содержимое
     newNode.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
     // нам надо другой id
     newNode.id = 'another'+element.id;
     // добавим этой копии класс newElement
     newNode.classList.add('newElement');
     // вставим измененный элемент в конец элемента clone
     clone.appendChild(newNode);
  });
  console.log(clone.innerHTML);
}



cloNeN();
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="ih" class="hello">Привет</div>
  <div id="ih1" class="goodbye">Пока</div>
  <div id="ih2" class="hello">Привет</div>
</div>

<div id="clone"></div>
```